# Не конвертируется цвет Background TreeViewItem через IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, style, treeview

Делаю как здесь http://www.sql.ru/forum/929430/wpf-c-peredacha-cveta-iz-metoda-i-ispolzovanie-ego-dlya-fona-animaciya

После запуска программы цвет Background TreeViewItem не меняется.

```
<TreeView>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False" >

                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding collection_node, ConverterParameter=color_text,Converter={StaticResource ConverterColor}}"></Setter>


public class ConverterColor : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
        {

            try
            {              

                return Brushes.Red; 

            }
            catch
            {

                return null;
            }


        }
```

Но если заменить на это то цвет изменится: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0000"></Setter>`

Comment: А так работает: `<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False"><Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/></Trigger>`?

Comment: Так работает...

Comment: Отлично, значит, проблема с Binding. У вас вызывается конвертер? Поставьте breakpoint в `Convert`.

Comment: Вызывается. На выходе из него `return Brushes.Orange;` "{Name=Orange, ARGB=(255, 255, 165, 0)}"

Comment: сработало с return Brushes.Red; тут явная проблема с Binding. Но я пробовал делать биндинг так {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, ConverterParameter=color_text,Converter={StaticResource ConverterColor}}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class ConverterColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ...
             return "#00ff00";
        ...


    }
}

{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, ConverterParameter=color_text,Converter={StaticResource ConverterColor}}
```